# Is it possible to link objects on a unique column?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm using Hibernate 3.2.7.ga and I'm wondering if the following is possible.

Let's say there are 3 objects: Person, Town and Mayor.

When registering a Person in the application, you're asked to enter his or her town of residence. This field is saved as a String.

In another part of the application, you can register a Town (with it's name, number of inhabitants, etc.). After the Town is registered, you can add a Mayor to this town.

However, it is not desired to create a Town object for every town that is entered with a Client. An object is only desired when a Mayor needs to be registered.

I'm wondering if, just bij using the String field in Person, you can get the Mayor of the Town the Person lives in.

I'm thinking along these lines of code:

```
public class Client.java
{
  @Id
  public Long id;

  @Column(nullable = true, ??? )
  public String townOfResidence;

  public Mayor getMayor()
  {
    ...
  }
}

public class Town.java
{
  @Id
  public Long id;

  @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
  public String name;

  @OneToOne
  public Mayor mayor;
}
```

I just tried thinking along the following lines:

```
@Transient
private Town townObject;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Town.class, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "town")
public Town getTown()
{
    return townObject;
}
```

Comment: Why Town of residence is type of String not Town ?

Comment: Because that way, the person registering the Client is free to type whatever he or she wants and isn't restricted to Town-objects available in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more an ERD issue than an ORM one.

Either you have a relationship between `Person` and `Town` or you don't. If you have, you can only select values in the reference attribute that are in keys in the referenced table, or null (if valid). If you don't have the relationship, you have no restrictions.

Of course, you do not need to have a relationship to try to mix them in a query/JPQL. Without relationship, your program may offer the list of `Town` as possible values for the `Person` town, without forcing them to pick one. Or you may do something like

```
 SELECT t FROM Town t WHERE t.name = ?
```

And pass the person town there. Of course too, then there is no security that it will be not null.

An alternative approach might be having two columns, one as a reference to a Town (allowing null) and other as a free text. If the town is in the table you use the reference, if it is not use the String. Of course, this complicates your program logic considerably.

Comment: I guess I'm sticking with 2 properties for now. One of the type `Town` and one of the type `String`. When saving a `Person`, I'll check for `Town` objects and when saving a `Town`, I'll update `Person` objects.

Answer (score 0):

With this design, you'll need to use a query to get the mayor of the town of the person:

```
select mayor from Town town
inner join town.mayor mayor
where town.name = :theTownOfResidenceOfTheClient
```

This query will have to be executed as part of the method of a DAO/Repository class. The mayor can't be available in a `getMayor()` method of the Client object.